# Getting invalid input syntax for integer: "n/a" in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I have Contact table. Which has one column, mobilenumber whose datatype is INTEGER.

```
Select COALESCE(mobilenumber, 'N/A') from Contact.
```

As per above query when mobilenumber will be null then 'N/A' should be displayed.

But mobilenumber column is integer, so am getting `invalid input syntax for integer:"N/A"`

I have tried to implement with cast function also, still am not able to avoid this error.
Can anyone please help me how to overcome this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the number to a string:

```
Select COALESCE(CAST(mobilenumber as VARCHAR(255)), 'N/A')
from Contact;
```

When you mix different types, SQL has to figure out the type of the expression.  By the rules of the language, strings are converted to numbers -- hence your error.

Comment: And remember: *always* convert NULL values to a display format *at the very end* of the query. If you work with literals instead of NULLs you get a great performance penalty in filters, joins, groupings , etc.

Comment: Thanks, will follow the same